# simple form validation with jquery serialize() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#send').click(function() { 

var names = $('#appontment_form').serialize();

//this is how my names variable look like
//doctor=Dr.Fathmath+Shahuda&date=2013-02-27&time=1900+-+1700&phone=

var doc = $(names).filter('doctor');

if(doc !='')
{
       $.ajax({
       type: "post",
       url:  "../../includes/jqueryRequireFiles/appointmentSave.php",
       data:names,
       success: function(data)
       { 
        $('#confir').text('Your Appointment Received..');
       }
       });
       return false;
 }
 });
});
```

I have a appontment form. when i click send link it will grab all the values in the textboxs and put it in the names variable through serialize() function. i want to filter the names variable and find out if any of the field is left not filled.. if only if then i will make the ajax part.. but its not working...any help

Answer (score 1):

When you use `$.serialize()` the variable content looks like `?key=value1&key=value2`. If you want to validate the form, just do it without serialize like

```js
var found_errors = false;
if($('#formfield1').val().trim() == "") {
    //Handle errors if field is empty
    found_errors = true;
}
```

And if no errors are found, serialize the form and send it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using jQuery validation plugin.
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: but im not using the form's submit button..im using a link to send iformation to another page